# Javascript не выполняется при загрузке HTML в Webview в Android

Tags: javascript, java, html, android

Доброе время суток!
 Столкнулся с такой проблемой - не выполняется javascript в Webview в Android
При этом хочу загрузить в него следующий HTML код присвоенный переменной String htmlcontent:

```html
String htmlcontent ="<html>"
+"<head>"
+"<script type="text/javascript">" 
 
+"function meldung()"
+"{"
+"alert ('Hallo Welt!');"
+"}"
+"</script>" 
+" </head>" 
+" <body>"    
               
+" <input type="button" value="Alert" onClick=meldung()>"
+" </body>"
+" </html>;
```

```
    Все настройки сделал:
    webView = new WebView(this);
    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("",  htmlcontent, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

но почему то при нажатии кнопки в Webview ничего не происходит.

Если сохранить этот html как Example.html и поместить его в assets папку и вызвать его так
         webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Example.html");
то все работает.

Кто знает как использовать первый вариант? Почему javascript не выполняется. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а если это добавить

```
...
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.loadUrl(...);
```

Comment: спасибо помогло только я использовал webview.loadData(...);